# Azure Service Bus For SQL & Windows Job Execution

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am new to Azure and asked for Azure service bus implementation by my CTO. I have two different needs and you can call it them business scenario for Azure Service Bus Implementation.

Case 1: We have multiple sql and windows jobs which are inter dependent. For example window job **A** need to run at 3:00 AM and it's related sql job **"S"** after successful run after 3:00 AM. But challenge is that we are not sure how much time job **"A"** will take as this data fetching related.

Now using Azure bu I need to send notification to job **"S"**"that job **"A"** is completed successfully and run now.

That is where we will setup our huge crone jobs loosely coupled and always run all inter related jobs on successful run of its preceding job.

Case 2: Our jobs servers will always be different while our database server will always be different and where would be Azure Service Bus be hosted?

Considering that I am newbie and learning Azure.

Comment: Why the tag azure-service-fabric? And what is your intended purpose for the azure service bus in this scenario?

Comment: @PeterBons As I am mentioned I am new to service bus and I thought azure-service-fabric is related to this. Now I edited and deleted the same. So in the given business scenarios I want to use azure service functionality and implement the same in our solution.

Comment: And how are these jobs to be triggered? What kind of jobs are we talking about (what exactly is a window job, and a slq job)? is it on-premises or in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Service Bus is a Cloud messaging platform, where you can create a Service Bus Namespace under your Azure subscription and start transferring messages via Queues and Topics.

Azure Service Bus cannot be hosted anywhere, only clients can be created for processing the messages from Queues or Topics. Based on the architecture, clients can be created at different services. The messages may act as a mode of communication between the services or triggers between the services.

Comment: Where queue and  topics will be stored?

Comment: In the user selected Azure data center, while creating the namespace. Check the available data centers here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/global-infrastructure/services/